# Find the different element in array and return its position

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Trying to solve this:

This array takes an array of animals in the format:

```
 ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep']
```

> The animals will all be the 'right way round' apart from 1 animal!
>   Your function should return its index position.
>   The animals will not always be sheep but it will always be a field of the same kind of animal.

I've tried different approaches, like array.sort(), but doing that I return the wrong index.

This is my code so far:

```
function findWrongWayAnimal (field) {
  for(let i =0; i<field.length; i++){
    if(field[i] !== field[i+1] || field[i] !== field[i-1]){
      return field.indexOf(field[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Whatever I do, whatever I change, it always returns 0 when the wrong-way animal is in the middle of the array.
Could anyone give me a hand with this, please?

Comment: Seems __homework__, At-least rephrase _Your function should return its index position._

Comment: what is the expected result that you want ?

Comment: It's not homework, I'm learning on my own at the moment.

Comment: I need to return the index of the wrong-way animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `&&` instead of `||`, because you need to check for whether it is different from at least 2 other elements. Also you need different checks for handle first and last elements of the array since they don't have `i-1` and `i+1` respectively.

```js
var animals1 = ['peehs', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep'];
var animals2 = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep']
var animals3 = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs']

function findWrongWayAnimal (field) {
  for(let i =0; i<field.length; i++){
  // Handle the first element of the array.
      if(i == 0) {
         if(field[i] !== field[i+1] && field[i] !== field[i+2]) {
            return 0;
         }
      // Handle the last element
      } else if(i == field.length && field[i] !== field[i-1] && field[i] !== field[i-2]) {
            return field.length - 1;
      } else if(field[i] !== field[i+1] && field[i] !== field[i-1]){
          return field.indexOf(field[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(findWrongWayAnimal(animals1));
console.log(findWrongWayAnimal(animals2));
console.log(findWrongWayAnimal(animals3));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a mixed bag of reduce and find

```js
var arr = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep']
var occurrences = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1;
  return obj;
}, {}); // count occurrences

console.log(
 // show the index of the item that has an occurrence of 1
 arr.indexOf(Object.keys(occurrences).find(key => occurrences[key] === 1))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var temp = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep'];

function findWrongWayAnimal (field) {
  for(let i =0; i<field.length; i++){
     for(let j =0; j<field.length; j++){
       if(field[i]!= field[j]){
          return j
       }
     }
  }
}

console.log(findWrongWayAnimal(temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your aproach is that the first step of the loop is i=0,
so field[i-1] is like saying field[-1], which returns undefined. So your function will always return 0, because field[0] !== undefined

Comment: But even if I don't add field[i-1], still returns 0.   for(let i =0; i<field.length; i++){
    if(field[i] !== field[i+1]){
      return field.indexOf(field[i]);
    }
  }

Comment: Ok, then there is a second flow too.
And this is field.indexOf(field[i]);

In fact, if you found out that field[i]!==field[i+1], you want to return i (or i+1).

The indexOf will give you the first element that matches, which is 0.
So, changing your return statement to return i+1; would do the job.

Only think to consider, what happens if the wrong value is the first on the array. Then, you should return 0;

But again, I am not sure how you want to define what is "wrong".